# struts html:image vs html:img

Tags: struts, struts-html

What is the difference between the following struts html tags:

"html:image" and "html:img"

I searched through the apache docs, but couldn't find the difference though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html:image renders a input tag of type 'image' (it's like a submit button but with an image face)

html:img renders a img tag to place an image